# Why does normal map look so low poly after baking?

Tags: uv, texture-baking, normal-map, retopology

So after I bake the normal map from high poly object to low poly object, it has these weird smooth patches sticking out of it.In the image below, you can see that there are quite a lot of low poly object sticking out of the mesh, but is that really the problem? Because some other objects baked relatively well even if they have a few spots sticking out. But then again, I know very little besides the absolute basics of baking and retopology.
[image]

So here's the normal map on the low poly object, and the normal map looks like this:

[image]

The normal map is 4096x4096. And so the high poly model looks something like this:
[image]

And here's how it looks when high poly is overlapping low poly model:
[image]

And here's the retopology I did for it:
[image]

It might be a bit low poly, so I made one with a higher poly count, and it looked like this:
[image]
[image]

So yeah, i have 0 idea what to do, I tried making different retopologies, changed the seams, changed the bake settings, but still got nearly the same results. I used extrusion of 0.02 m and max ray distance is also 0.02 m. I haven't baked the cavity map yet, because I think it won't affect it at all, if the normal map is bad.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hello could you please share your high and low poly pants?

Comment: You should use cage object

Comment: @moonboots https://skfb.ly/oIArr here's the low poly, and here's the high poly: https://skfb.ly/oIArJ

Comment: @Karan I tried, but I got pretty much the same results

Comment: If these objects are copyright free, could you please share your blend file with both the 2 object instead?

Comment: @moonboots Sure! Here's the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Me4j-RXK4dPwfGdrju-34Z3BiUc4HLNo/view?usp=sharing, though I'm don't think the normal maps were imported as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve used *pants-lp-first* as low-poly, applied the *Mirror* modifier, shaded smooth, unwrapped with the *Smart UV Project* option, created a *32-Bit Float* image, chosen an *Extrusion* of 0.1, baked, and it seems to work, on the left the high-poly, on the right the low-poly:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess I'll try to pin point the exact thing that was the game changer for this one, but I guess it might be because I didn't use the 32-bit float image. But agian, thank you so much!!